# Can I alter the iOS 7 code on my Mac and then load it onto my iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ios7

I was wondering if it's possible to alter or modify the iOS code and then boot it onto my iPhone using my Mac.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I use my Mac every day to write iOS code and put the app on my iPhone. You must mean something different.

Comment: Yes I don't mean for developing an app in Xcode and then running it on my iPhone I mean downloading iOS 7.1 from the developer center opening the code files on my computer and edit them like text and those kind of things then bundling it back together and then booting it onto my 5s.

Comment: It might be possible if your device is jailbroken otherwise not a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Without a jailbreak, the code for iOS itself cannot be altered. iOS apps are sandboxed, meaning they can only modify files or settings in that app ([generally](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW2)), and are not able to communicate with each other very well, let alone the OS.